# What's with bad function call in view generated via scaffold?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffold

I've scaffolded Things element:

```
script/generate scaffold wip/thing name:string
```

and got some invalid function call in views, like:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_thing_path(thing) %></td>
```

Which raise this error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError (undefined method `edit_thing_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0xb5c00944>) on line #11 of app/views/wip/things/index.html.erb:                                                                                                                                 
8:   <tr>                                                                                                                                  
9:     <td><%=h thing.name %></td>
10:     <td><%= link_to 'Show', thing %></td>
11:     <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_thing_path(thing) %></td>
12:     <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', thing, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
13:   </tr>
14: <% end %>
```

What's with that function? Where is it? Is it some kind of automagic stuff or do I need to implement it (if so - where should it go?)

I have resource defined in routes with namespace:

```
  map.namespace :wip do |wip|
    wip.resources :things
  end
```

rake routes gives me this:

```
                                wip_things GET    /wip/things(.:format)                                                            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"wip/things"}
                                           POST   /wip/things(.:format)                                                            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"wip/things"}
                             new_wip_thing GET    /wip/things/new(.:format)                                                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"wip/things"}
                            edit_wip_thing GET    /wip/things/:id/edit(.:format)                                                   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"wip/things"}
                                 wip_thing GET    /wip/things/:id(.:format)
```

I assumed that those names (wip_thing, new_wip_thing) are the correct names, but it's still gives me that error

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got it! The method should be as suggested by

```
rake routes
```

but should have suffix _path:

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_wip_thing_path(@thing) %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This method come from your routes.rb file. If you have a resource :thing define, all of this method are define in your controller/views.

Check on your `config/routes.rb`file if you are :

`map.resources :things`

If you don't have this resource, this methode is not define.

Check about this resource on Ruby on Rails guides : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

You can know all of this routes with the rake task :

`rake routes`

Comment: I have this resource but defined in namespace:
  map.namespace :wip do |wip|
    wip.resources :things
  end
is it something wrong with that?

Comment: Yes it is. The scaffold define route without namespace. You need define the url with this namespace. See rake routes to see the real route

Comment: Ok, I ran rake routes, and got "
new_wip_thing GET    /wip/things/new(.:format)                                                        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"wip/things"}
"
So I tried to use "new_wip_thing" in my view, but it still raises an error. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?